# Number formatting using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to format a number such as "1234567891234" into "123-45678-912-34" using native javascript? There are many solutions available but I am wondering which one is best? Please advise

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: If there are many solutions, post them here so we can review them, or are we supposed to search the web for these "many solutions" ?

Comment: The best one is the one that you decide is best and most applicable to your problem at hand. Since you've acknowledged that there are many solutions, you should just choose one.

Comment: Is it always a 13 digit number?  Are you always using `-`?  Are they always inserted in those specific positions?

Comment: 'Which one is best' is a matter of opinion, and thus not suited to SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the following:

```
var unformatted="1234567891234"
var groups=/^(\d{3})(\d{5})(\d{3})(\d{2}$)/.exec(unformatted)
var formatted=groups[1]+"-"+groups[2]+"-"+groups[3]+"-"+groups[4]
console.log(formatted)
```